# Match input starting with non-number or empty string followed by specific pattern

Tags: java, regex, greedy, character-class

I'm using Java regular expressions to match and capture a string such as:

`0::10000`

A solution would be:

`(0::\d{1,8})`

However, the match would succeed for the input

`10::10000`

As well, which is wrong. Therefore, I now have:

`\[^\d\](0::\d{1,8})`

Which means it must lead with any character except a number, but that means there needs to be **some** character before the first zero. What I really want (and what I need help with) is to say "lead with a non-number or nothing at all."

In conclusion the final solution regular expression **should match** the following:

```
0::10000
kjkj0::10000
```

And **should not** match the following:

```
10::10000
```

[This site](http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html) may be of use if someone wants to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!\d)(0::\d{1,8})
```

It means "match `0::\d{1,8}` not preceded by `\d`".